Cast column types for a table sourced from json
I parsed a json table and I ended up with many columns of mixed type.
([]col1:("tet1";"test2";());col2:(234j;0b;33j);col3:("sda";0b;"");col4:(0b;"";"dadd"))

I know that:
 col1 - symbol
 col2 - long
 col3 - float 
 col4 - string 

How can I get rid of illegal chars and parse the columns.
Please bear in mind that doing each is to be avoided (100 mil rows x 220 cols)

You say col3 - float  but none of it's contents look like number col3:("sda";0b;"") - what should the result be? Could you include the expected output of the table after cleansing.

"doing each is to be avoided"
When dealing with mixed lists of type 0h with mixed contents it is inevitable you will need iterators. Below each right /: is used.
You can build on some of the cast helper tips included in:
https://kx.com/blog/kdb-q-insights-parsing-json-files/
q)t:([]col1:("tet1";"test2";());col2:(234j;0b;33j);col3:("sda";0b;"");col4:(0b;"";"dadd"))

q)generalHelper:{[t;d]![t;();0b;key[d]!{(x;y)}'[value d;key d]]}

q)cleanseRules:`long`symbol`string`float!(
    {@[x;where 0b~/:x;:;0N]};
    {i:where ()~/:x;`$@[x;i;:;count[i]#enlist ""]};
    {i:where 0b~/:x;@[x;i;:;count[i]#enlist ""]};
    {i:where 0b~/:x;"F"$@[x;i;:;count[i]#enlist ""]}
 )

q)colRules:`col1`col2`col3`col4!`symbol`long`float`string

q)generalHelper[;cleanseRules colRules] t
col1  col2 col3 col4
----------------------
tet1  234       ""
test2           ""
      33        "dadd"

These would need tweaking to your exact incoming JSON data and outcome requirements.
Multiple cores can be used by reworking generalHelper to use peach
q)generalHelper:{[t;d] t[key d]:{y[1]x[y 0]}[t] peach flip (key d;value d);t}

q)generalHelper[;cleanseRules colRules] t
col1  col2 col3 col4
----------------------
tet1  234       ""
test2           ""
      33        "dadd"


https://code.kx.com/q/basics/cmdline/#-s-secondary-threads

